# Нужно ли обособлять оборот со словом "к счастью"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

*У Светы какой глубокий и чистый взгляд, какое милое и просто ангельское личико, и как её можно, к счастью мира всего этого, не любить и не понимать?!*

Объясните, пожалуйста, выделяется ли оборот со словом "к счастью"? Или это выделение зависит от позиции автора?

Comment: Что-то название вопроса не совпадает с самим вопросом, где здесь местоимение ЧТО?

Answer (score 1):

У *Светы какой глубокий и чистый взгляд, какое милое и просто ангельское личико, и как её можно, к счастью мира всего этого, не любить и не понимать?!*

...**к счастью мира всего этого** - вводное сочетание, поэтому выделяется запятыми. Правда, я не понимаю его роли в ЭТОМ предложении. Предложение вопросительно-восклицательное, что там происходит к счастью? Да ещё всего мира? Вводное сочетание, мне думается, здесь вообще не к месту.

Само предложение тоже лучше бы поправить, обычно такого типа предложения начинаются с вопросительного слова:  *Какой глубокий и чистый взгляд у Светы, какое милое и просто ангельское личико  -  и как её можно не любить и не понимать?!*

Или убрать вопросительность первой части:

*У Светы **такой** глубокий и чистый взгляд, **такое** милое и просто ангельское личико, и как её можно не любить и не понимать?!*

Можно разделить части:

*У Светы такой глубокий и чистый взгляд, такое милое и просто ангельское личико! И как  можно её  не любить и не понимать ?!*

Answer (score 0):

Предложение нуждается  в редактировании, так как оборот явно не на месте.

1) В качестве варианта:

*У Светы такой глубокий и чистый взгляд, такое милое и просто ангельское личико, и как её можно не любить и не понимать!  **К счастью мира всего этого**, еще существуют такие люди.*

Теперь оборот можно определить как вводную конструкцию и обособить.

Такие обороты не обособляются, если являются обстоятельством и входят в основной состав предложения, например: *Такие люди рождаются (для чего?) для счастья всего мира.*

2) Еще один вариант:

*У Светы такой глубокий и чистый взгляд, такое милое и просто ангельское личико, и как  можно её,  **счастье мира всего этого**, не любить и не понимать!*

Здесь обособляется приложение, отнесенное к местоимению.